# Making Class and Object with Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make a class and object but the errors that I get are

```
Error: Field 'questionText' should be initialized because its type 'String' doesn't allow null.
  String questionText;
Error: Field 'questionAnswer' should be initialized because its type 'bool' doesn't allow null.
  bool questionAnswer;
```

```dart
class Question{
  String questionText;
  bool questionAnswer;

  Question({String q, bool a}){
    questionText = q;
    questionAnswer= a;
  }
}
```

Comment: Change String to String? and bool to bool? Or use {required String q, required bool a}. For more information check https://dart.dev/null-safety

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialization rules are more strict with this introduction of null safety in dart. See [Uninitialized variables](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#uninitialized-variables):

> Instance fields must either have an initializer at the declaration, use an initializing formal, or be initialized in the constructor’s initialization list. That’s a lot of jargon. Here are the examples:
>
> ```
> // Using null safety:
> class SomeClass {
>  int atDeclaration = 0;
>  int initializingFormal;
>  int initializationList;
>
>  SomeClass(this.initializingFormal)
>      : initializationList = 0;
> }
> ```

In your case, you are using named parameters, so you need to mark them as required as well (or use positional ones)

```
class Question{
  String questionText;
  bool questionAnswer;

  Question({required String q, required bool a}) :
    questionText = q,
    questionAnswer= a;
}
```

Alternative with initializing formal and named parameters: (Note that class fields and named parameters need to have the same name)

```
class Question{
  String questionText;
  bool questionAnswer;

  Question({required this.questionText, required this.questionAnswer});
}
```

Comment: thank you sir, now i am better than yesterday. thanks

Comment: @Arthupay If my answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing is that if you use named parameters, not putting "required" implies that the parameters are optional. And you cannot assign a variable of type String? (which is String or null) to a variable of type String. This is why you could not assign "q" to "questionText".

You can make the properties optional:

```
class Question{
  String? questionText;
  bool? questionAnswer;

  Question({String q, bool a}){
    questionText = q;
    questionAnswer= a;
  }
}
```

Or you can make the parameters required:

```
class Question{
  String questionText;
  bool questionAnswer;

  Question({required String q,required bool a}){
    questionText = q;
    questionAnswer= a;
  }
}
```

And a simpler way to do this is like this:

```
class Question{
  String questionText;
  bool questionAnswer;

  Question({required String this.questionText, required bool this.questionAnswer});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is issue with flutter Quizzler task from flutter course,

Error:
Non-nullable instance field 'questionAnswer' must be initialized.
Non-nullable instance field 'questionText' must be initialized.

[original format - see img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOxYd.png)

```
class Question {
  String questionText;
  bool questionAnswer;

  Question({String q, bool a}) { //remove '{', replace with ':'
    questionText = q;            //remove ';', replace with ','
    questionAnswer = a;
  }                              //remove extra '{'
}
```

To solve it you just need to reformat constructor:

[reformatted constructor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFkJN.png)

```
class Question {
  String questionText;
  bool questionAnswer;

  Question({required String q, required bool a}) :
    questionText = q,
    questionAnswer = a;
}
```

you'll probably need to add 'required' because values can't be null.